# ３次元配列の各要素を配列に置き換えたい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, julia

```
N=2
a = zeros(Float32,N,N,N)

2×2×2 Array{Float32,3}:

    [:, :, 1] =
     0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0

    [:, :, 2] =
     0.0  0.0
     0.0  0.0
```

の各要素にたとえば[0,0,0,0]を割り振りたいのですが、Juliaではどのようにやるのでしょうか。。？
pythonでは

```
N=2
a = np.zeros((N,N,N,4),dtype=np.float32)
```

でことが済むのですが、、、
ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: `a = zeros(Float32,N,N,N,4)` とするのではダメなのでしょうか？ 例えば、`a[1,1,1,:]` とすれば `[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]` が割り振られている事が分かるかと思います。ご存知かもしれませんが、numpy の `shape` に相当するのは `size` ですので、`size(a)` を実行すると `(2, 2, 2, 4)` と表示されます。

Comment: あ、なるほど！やはりそれで大丈夫でしたか、、。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 今動かしてみたら、完全に理解しました！